# Karma : Angular 4 No provider for Service

Tags: angular, karma-runner

Hi would like to test the real service with in my angular component. but im getting below error. **No provider for Service blservice**

```
import {async, getTestBed,TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BlService } from './bl.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, ResponseOptions, XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';

describe('BlService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [BlService]
   });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([BlService], (service: BlService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

**ERROR :**

> Error: No provider for BlService! Error: No provider for BlService!
>   at ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._throwOrNull
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42115:13)
>   at ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42154:13)
>   at ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42086:13)
>   at ReflectiveInjector_.prototype.get
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:41955:9)    at
>   resolveNgModuleDep
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:48958:5)    at
>   NgModuleRef_.prototype.get
>   (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:50028:9)

Comment: can any one help on this please

Answer (score 29):

Solve it this way:

```
import {async} from '@angular/core/testing';


beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [BlService]
  });
}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not too smart implementing this answer. Shortcut for others having problems implementing this like me, use async(()=>{}) inside the describe/it method where you are having the problem. Not just on beforeEach... I'm not too smart sometimes. Thanks again.